# Html attribute enumeration

Tags: c#, html

I am using `HtmlAgilityPack` to parse a html document. In the document I want to get the attributes of a selected node. As for example below is the file structure:

```
<table ########">
    <tr id="tableHeaderColor">
        <th scope="col">Something</th>
        <th scope="col">Something</th>
        <th scope="col">Something</th>
        <th scope="col">Something</th>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="top">
        <td>Something</td>
        <td>Something</td>
        <td>Something</td>
        <td>Something</td>
    </tr>
```

I want to find if the `/tr` node has `id` or `valign`.

Comment: Let me know if i am clear in my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have a reference to the specific node that you are looking for, there is a collection on it called `Attributes`.

```
var valign = node.Attributes["valign"].Value
```

Comment: This helps me to get the value of the attribute, but I was looking more into getting the attribute itself.
I would like to find what attribute is under the /tr node. In this case I have two such, "id" and "valign".